# How to determine the first and last row of unordered list <ul> element by click function using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to accurately determine the first and last row of my looped unordered list which contains records by just clicking them. This unordered list holds records which are binded from the database.

For example, if this is my sample html:

```
     <div id="container">
       <ul id="Unorderedlist" >
           <li id="ListofContent" class="ul-content">              
                <div id="divcontent" class="divcontent">                    
                <label id="filenames" class="filenames"></label>
                </div>                 
           </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

If I want to click the first row of that unordered list, it will throw an alert saying **"This is the first row."** something like this below:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".filenames", function () {
// Please add something here...

alert("This is the first row.");
});
```

And if I want to click the last row of that unordered list, it will throw an alert saying **"This is the last row."** something like this below:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".filenames", function () {
// Please add something here...

alert("This is the last row.");
});
```

How would I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) pseudo-class selectors.

```
$("#container").on("click", ".filenames:first", function () {    
  alert("This is the first row.");
}).on("click", ".filenames:last", function () {
  alert("This is the last row.");
});
```

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".filenames:first", function() {
  alert("This is the first row.");
}).on("click", ".filenames:last", function() {
  alert("This is the last row.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul id="Unorderedlist">
    <li id="ListofContent" class="ul-content">
      <div id="divcontent" class="divcontent">
        <label id="filenames" class="filenames">Click</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="ListofContent" class="ul-content">
      <div id="divcontent" class="divcontent">
        <label id="filenames" class="filenames">Click</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="ListofContent" class="ul-content">
      <div id="divcontent" class="divcontent">
        <label id="filenames" class="filenames">Click</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Using css [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) pseudo-class selectors.

```
$("#container").on("click", "li:first-child .filenames", function () {    
  alert("This is the first row.");
}).on("click", "li:last-child .filenames", function () {
  alert("This is the last row.");
});
```

```js
$("#container").on("click", "li:first-child .filenames", function() {
  alert("This is the first row.");
}).on("click", "li:last-child .filenames", function() {
  alert("This is the last row.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul id="Unorderedlist">
    <li id="ListofContent" class="ul-content">
      <div id="divcontent" class="divcontent">
        <label id="filenames" class="filenames">Click</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="ListofContent" class="ul-content">
      <div id="divcontent" class="divcontent">
        <label id="filenames" class="filenames">Click</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="ListofContent" class="ul-content">
      <div id="divcontent" class="divcontent">
        <label id="filenames" class="filenames">Click</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```